# Red Hat JBoss Fuse 6.2.1: Osgi Missing Requirement: Oracle JDBC Driver

Tags: jboss, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle

This is a problem that I am facing with Jboss fuse, where a dependency (Oracle JDBC JAR) is not found as an OSGI bundle. 
The source code works fine when run locally, but errors out when deployed on a Karaf container.
A detailed explanation of the issue and associated source code is placed at:
https://developer.jboss.org/message/948643

Any suggestions on this would be welcome.

Thanks for your patience.
Prabal

Comment: giyf: http://cq-ops.tumblr.com/post/21893960212/how-to-turn-a-jdbc-driver-jar-into-an-osgi-bundle / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16892212/osgi-bundle-requires-jdbc-driver-when-using-service-interface-from-other-bundle

Comment: Please include the details of the problem in the question, not at an external link. This is StackOverflow policy because the external link may become stale, and the question and its answer will no longer be useful.

Comment: I am trying to deploy a Fuse project which uses the Oracle JDBC driver. While I can run the source code successfully in the Jboss developer studio, I am unable to deploy into a Karaf container. Whenever I try doing that I get an error as follows:
 
onFramework [307]: Unable to resolve 307.0: missing requirement [307.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=oracle.jdbc)

Comment: Here is what I tried to fix this:
- Deploy this as a FAB but get the following error:
osgi:install fab:mvn:au.com.nbnco/ASN_CommonFramework/1.0.0Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: Unknown protocol: fab
  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:620)[:1.8.0_66]

Comment: - Modify the POM file (ref lines 358-359) to Oracle driver jar as an embedded dependency.
Changed the following from:
<Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
to
<Import-Package>!oracle.jdbc,*</Import-Package>
<Embed-Dependency>ojdbc6</Embed-Dependency>    However this raises a new setof dependencies in
\target\classes\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF
Import-Package: com.sun.security.auth.module,javax.crypto,javax.crypto.s
pec,javax.management,javax.naming,javax.naming.directory,javax.naming.s
pi,javax.net,javax.net.ssl,javax.resource,...and many others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Oracle JAR File that you are trying to deploying on the Fuse Server is not a Maven Bundle.
So you'll need to Wrap and install the library using the following command :

```
install -s wrap:mvn:com.oracle/ojdbc6/<version>
```

Where the `<version>` refers to the version number of the jar file.  Hope this helps.